# Is there any equivalent function with clock_gettime in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, clock

I have tried clock_gettime in Mac OS, but gcc complains that can not find this symbol.
I don't know why...... I just wanna use nanosecond to record performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get microseconds from `gettimeofday(2)`.  Is that perhaps enough?

Comment: I think it is not enough because I am testing malloc and free pair of a lib... but thank you very very much. I have seen another function in mac os, mach_absolute_time(), someone said that it can be used for computing nanosecond duration.

Comment: I'd be surprised if `mach_absolute_time()` or any system call can give you the accuracy you want.  Any context switch will screw up the timings, also `malloc()` itself may vary depending on whether it needs to make a system call to get more virtual memory.  And `mach_absolute_time()` probably takes a while to execute in terms of nanoseconds.

Comment: If you want to time something small, generally you have no choice but to execute the procedure many (hundreds of thousands) of times and get an average.  The clock accuracy generally simply isn't good enough to time a single call reliably.

Comment: @JeremyP, thank you for telling me this. I found that first time malloc-free pair takes thousands of nanoseconds, this may because of virtual memory.

Comment: @StevenSchlansker thank you very much, I do think this is a better way to solve that